# How do i create an input that adds elements to an array?

Tags: php, arrays, html, input

I'm sure someone must have asked this, however even if i searched before asking (most of my questions weren't well received) i can't find the answer to the following question: 
Is there any kind of function, that lets you add a string to your array.

 E.g.

```
    <form action="workerPage.php" method="POST" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Add string to array" name="firstİnput">
    <input type="submit" value="Add!!">
    </form>
```

And then, when i submit, it will automatically add to an array which i have in my php page, workerPage.php 
Thank you so much for your help in advance!

Comment: What do you mean adds elements to an array? Do you have an attempted code?

Comment: HTML doesn't have any notion of "arrays" whatsoever. If you want to add something, *anything*, to a PHP array, you need to write PHP code for that. What specific problem do you have doing so?

Comment: İ do not no how to do it! Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to pass it as an array you can simply do this:

```
 <input type="text" placeholder="Add string to array" name="firstİnput[]">
```

If you wish to add it to an existing array you will need to process the value in your workerPage.php script

Answer (score 0):

you can use either

```
array_push($data, $POST['firstInput'])
```

or do

```
$data[] = $POST['firstInput'];
```

Your array should be saved on the webserver e.g. in a session or file.

Comment: And is there a way to get

Comment: the added string back with an other input. For example, if i search for it with an other input, will it appear back?